# query about dev c++-running programs

Tags: ide, dev-c++

Can anybody tell me how I can paste text input into the Dev-C++ console (command line shell) while running a program in Dev-C++?
Also is there any other simple IDE which allows users to work with a single source file w/o creating a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

af far as i can remember dev-cpp start a windows commadline window when a consol application is started. so if you have somethig like

```
cout << "enter a char: ";
cin >> c;
```

in your code, the consol window will be wating for input.

an to your second question: Yes and No

Yes: you can use g++.exe (witch comes with dev-cpp) and notepade.exe (witch comses with windows)
and compile your source using commad `g++.exe source.cpp` and run you application by typing `a.exe` in a console window witch you have to open yourself and navigate to the directory where source.cpp is located.

No: (g++.exe + notepade.exe) == IDE

Note that you have to extend the PATH envirenment variable to be able to use g++.exe without fullpath to it

Comment: Well if u read carefully i said that i wanted 2 paste(and not type) input into the window

Comment: OK, try right-click over the widnow and paste or click the icon on the upper left corner of the window than edit > paste

Comment: ok, right clicking on the title bar brings the edit option having paste,thanks!